# Can Durandaljs do Areas

Tags: durandal

I'm trying to see if there is a way to do areas in Durandaljs

Something along the lines of

```
/App/areas/home
                /views
                /viewmodels
          /other
                /views
                /viewmodels
```

I see the viewLocator allowing this convention:

```
 viewLocator.useConvention('viewmodels', 'views', 'areas');
```

but the router.useConvention() seems to default to same path.

Is there a proper way to account for this, the documentation is light in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do this.

Since you are using Durandal.router you can use a convention of where to find your ViewModels by overriding the routers autoConvertRouteToModuleId like so:

```
router.autoConvertRouteToModuleId = function(url, params) {
    return url + '/' + 'params[0]';
};
```

As for finding the view that binds to your viewmodel then you can like you have above.. change the viewlocator convention.