# How to setup durandaljs with Areas?

Tags: single-page-application, durandal

For the life of me I can't make durandaljs work with Areas. I'm developing an application with multiple mini SPAs, but I'm not sure how to set up durandaljs to work with it. I wasn't able to find anything online that can drive me in the right direction. The only similar question I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416494/can-durandaljs-do-areas), which is very vague.

My goal is to separate each SPA within it's own folder like so:

```
App
--areas
----area1
------viewmodels
------views
----area2
------viewmodels
------views
```

The router doesn't seem to have the concept of `areas` and no matter how I map the routes I get `404s` when I call `router.activate('page1');` after mapping with `router.mapRoute('page1');` durandal is trying to get `/App/viewmodels/page1.js`.

Changing it to:

```
router.mapRoute('areas/area1/viewmodels/page1');
router.activate('areas/area1/viewmodels/page1');
```

results in another `404` fetching `App/viewmodels/areas/area1/viewmodels/page1.js`
I've also tried many other combinations which I no longer remember and can't seem to get it to work.

Can someone please post a working example of how to setup durandaljs with the router plugin and multiple mini SPAs (areas)? A link to an article document would also suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `viewLocator.useConvention` - maybe something like this:

```
viewLocator.useConvention(
                    "areas/area1/viewmodels",
                    "areas/area1/views",
                    "areas/area1/templates"
);
```

One good thing to realize is that `useConvention()` works in conjunction with any existing require.config `paths` setting.  In other words, if you set the require.config so that "viewModels" and "views" are mapped to the right folders, then all is well.

For example, the code snippet above is functionally equivalent to:

```
window.require.config({
    paths: {
        "viewModels": "areas/area1/viewmodels",
        "views": "areas/area1/views",
        "templates": "areas/area1/templates"
    }

viewLocator.useConvention("viewmodels", "views", "templates");
```

Comment: how would I set up the routes? Simply using `router.mapRoute('page1');`?

Comment: I would set it up like this: **using require.config:** `router.mapNav("page1", "viewModels/page1", displayName, visible)`  **or without require.config:** `router.mapNav("page1", "areas/area1/viewmodels/page1", displayName, visible)`.  That way the url stays clean and simple (like `http://localhost/area1/page1`), but the actual module path can be as complicated as you want.

Comment: Are you using actual MVC areas?

Comment: so, this solved the problem. I ended up using the config approach with the `router.mapNav("page1", "viewmodels/page1");`

Answer (score 1):

I a similar structure implemented in my application. I think that you have to put this piece of code, to do the viewLocator works properly.

```
viewLocator.useConvention(); //You can do that in you main.js
```

You can see more information here: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/View-Locator/

Also I recommed you to look the code of viewLocator.js, especially, the code of useConventionMethod.

Other possibility is to override the method convertModuleIdToViewId, to make it works as you want. But I think that using useConvention methos is enought.